# file managing - text file managing java

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream

I've been  trying  to create files  inside some directories but haven't been able to figure it out.

The point is to create text files inside  package `dir`: `com.resources.files` but my idea  doesn't  work.

```
public boolean archiveFile() {
          //  
        InputStream str = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/resources/files/"+Filename.txt
        boolean  bol = false;

            file = new File(  str.toString()   );
        if(!file.exists()) {
            try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    bol = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }// try-catch           
        }else {
            bol = false;
        } //  if - else 
            return bol;         
    }//  archiveFile
```

Comment: new File(  str.toString()   ); won't work. You have a stream, then you have to read from there. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string

Comment: what does `getClass().getResourceAsStream` do ? first time to see this

Answer (score 1):

Resources are not files, and resource paths are not directories. Consider the case where a WAR file is being executed without unzipping.

You can't do this.

Comment: ok so can you give me a link o help me understand what the correct procedure is please ?